# How do I update a pandas Datafame column on the condition of 2 other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To simplify lets say I have the following dataframe:

```
   Name1       Nickname
0    Tom   Tommy 2 toes
1    Nan  Stevie Wonder
2   Mark     Marky Mark
3  Clark            Nan
```

I need to create a new column 'First Name' on the following condition.
If Name1 exists, update First Name with Name1. Else update with Nickname.

The output should look like this:

```
   Name1       Nickname     First Name
0    Tom   Tommy 2 toes            Tom       
1    Nan  Stevie Wonder  Stevie Wonder
2   Mark     Marky Mark           Mark
3  Clark            Nan          Clark
```

Ive been trying variations of:

```
df['First Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Name1'] if x['Name1'] is True else x['Nickname'], axis=1)
```

But this appears to just update First Name column with all of one or the other Name1 or Nickname columns. With other searching it looks like I would be better off with using df.loc but I can't find an applicable solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have this df:

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({"names":['a','b',np.nan], "nicknames":['aa', 'bb', 'cc']})
>>> a
  names nicknames
0     a        aa
1     b        bb
2   NaN        cc
```

Then to fill in the nans of names:

```
>>> a['First Name'] = a["names"].fillna(a['nicknames'])
>>> a
  names nicknames First Name
0     a        aa          a
1     b        bb          b
2   NaN        cc         cc
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['a', 'b', np.nan, 'c'],
    'nickname': ['f', 'g', 'i', 'k']
})
print(df)

Output:

    name    nickname
0   a       f
1   b       g
2   NaN     i
3   c       k
```

You need:

```
#import numpy as np
df['First name'] = np.where(df['name'].isnull(), df['nickname'], df['name'])
```